# Error when trying to mock the NavController

Tags: android, mockito, androidx

Trying to follow the example https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-testing, I have an expected error

**org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:
Mockito cannot mock this class: class androidx.navigation.NavController.**

even after include all the dependencies as here: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/set-up-project

```java
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class MyShopFragmentTest {

    @Test
    fun testMyShopScenario_F001() {
        // Create a mock NavController
        val mockNavController = mock(NavController::class.java)

        // Create a graphical FragmentScenario for the MyShopFragment
        val myShopFragmentScenario = launchFragmentInContainer<MyShopFragment>()

        // Set the NavController property on the fragment
        myShopFragmentScenario.onFragment { fragment ->
            Navigation.setViewNavController(fragment.requireView(), mockNavController)
        }

        // Verify that performing a click prompts the correct Navigation action
        onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.search)).perform(ViewActions.click())
        verify(mockNavController).navigate(R.id.searchFragment)
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: I feel like you don't initialize the mock correctly. Try to use Annotations
`@Mock val mockNavController;` and initialize it with `@Rule public MockitoRule rule = MockitoJUnit.rule();`. You can inject mocks in other classes with `@InjectMocks private Classname injectedClassname`.

Comment: was a problem in gradle config. SOLVED!

Comment: Great. You should either close your Question or write your own Answer and mark it. Just for godo measures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was use the all-open annotation (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html) and configure the project as described here --> https://developer.android.com/training/testing/set-up-project

Answer (score 7):

For me, changing my dependency from

```
androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:3.2.4'
```

to

```
androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-android:3.2.4'
```

worked well.